# Uploading Image to server with text paramater iPhone

Tags: iphone, web-services, image-uploading

I am developing application which require uploading the Image from the iphone to Php Server, Following is the code i used to upload the file to server but I can see only the text parameter but the Image is not getting uploaded .

```
  NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";
NSString* FileParamConstant = @"image";

 NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://bb.trackfleet.biz/smscalling/upload_iphone_image.php"]; 

    NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   [_params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"919964823246"] forKey:@"contact"];



    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
    [request setTimeoutInterval:60];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


    // post body
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    // add params (all params are strings)
    for (NSString *param in _params) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    UIImage *imageToPost=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.jpg"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToPost, 1.0);
    if (imageData) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:imageData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }



    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // set the content-length
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

    // set URL
    [request setURL:requestURL];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
```

Problem: Image is not getting uploaded at the path  where has the text is stored in database .

What I Did: For some reference, I tried Flickr API iOS app "POST size too large!" and Objective C: How to upload image and text using HTTP POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you.I tried this post: ["image upload tutorial iOS".](http://activehigh.wordpress.com/2011/09/14/uploading-files-from-iphone-to-asp-net-web-site/)